# Calculating Course cost per student

Tags: views, rules

My Scenario:
One admin user is entering these information.
I have 3 content types: student, register, course.
Student is obvious, i.e. student_number, personal_info, etc
Course contains: course_name & course_costs, etc.
Register contains: ref to course, course_date, ref to students who attend this course.

My question: How would I go about calculating/working out costs per student, per course?

Do I need to use rules? I assume commerce is out of the picture, as one admin user is entering this information. Any direction would help. Thank you.

Comment: where you like to display this calculated amount to be shown? Can you please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Hi Ashish
The display would probably be a report to print out (views). I forgot to mention the reason why I do it this way, is so I can also print out a class register with it's unique number - attendance report (register content type).

Comment: Sound like you needs to have a look at the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module ... Can you provide more details about your actual calculation? And why do you think you need Rules, eg what kind of Event should trigger some rule?

Comment: Hi Pierre
Well, the course cost is on the course content type. I need to know if 10 students attended a class which cost $10... then my total for the class is $100 on my attendance register. Attendance register (register content type) would do the calculations, but this can be a view also depending which one works best. I need to show the students who attended and the amount for each student although the amount is captured once on the course content type. I'll have a look at the Forena module. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this value stored on the Register Content Type?

You can use the [`computed_field` module](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field).

You will need to read every value in `ref_to_course` field. Load each of those nodes. From there, read the `course_cost` and add the values.

Then store the values on the computed field.

---

Another option is using [`views` module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). You can attach a View to the content type. The view can then use the node `NID`, read the `ref_to_course`. Add relationship, read the `course_cost` and add those.

---

I think the first might be better since you calculate it once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer rovr138. No, the course cost will be on the course content type, and the total costs of the students attending the course can just be a view linked to the register number (register content type).
I hope this makes sense.